# Modeling Gaussian components with standard vs exact functions

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-modeling, error-function

I'm studying a paper on modeling DNA histograms. It presents two alternative formulas for modeling Gaussian components:

## Standard form:

$G(x) = \frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\Delta x $

## Exact form:

$G(x) = \frac{A}{2\sigma}(erf(\frac{x + 0.5 - \mu}{\sqrt{2\sigma}}) - erf(\frac{x - 0.5 - \mu}{\sqrt{2\sigma}}))$

The author recommends the exact form over the standard form, especially when $\sigma$ is low. However, when I plot both in gnuplot, they aren't the same: the exact form produces higher values for the same parameters (I've set A = 1.0, sd = 1.0, mu = 0.0, the purple line is the standard form, the blue line is the exact form):
[image: Normal Functions]

No explanation is provided for why one form is better than the other.

## Questions

1. Why don't the functions match? Am I misinterpreting something?
2. Why would the Exact Form, using the error function, be better than the standard form - I guess maybe it is numerically faster or more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be considering something like:

$$P\left ( x-\frac{\Delta x}{2} \leq X \leq x+\frac{\Delta x}{2} \right )$$

where $X$ is Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. This is exactly equal to

$$\int_{x-\Delta x/2}^{x+\Delta x/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} e^{-(y-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} dy$$

which can be straightforwardly rewritten in terms of the error function, if desired. When $\Delta x$ is much less than $\sigma$, we can reasonably approximate this integral using the midpoint rule with $1$ point: we get

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2 \sigma^2)} \Delta x.$$

Comment: I think I follow. In the 'Exact form' equation above, $\Delta$ x/2 = 0.5 then? If the Exact Form and Standard Form are the same equation rewritten in different ways, why don't the plots match?

Comment: @Tyler They're not the same equation. The "standard form" is an approximation of the "exact form". That said, if $\sigma$ is large enough, you should find that your "exact form" (in which $\Delta x = 1$) is well approximated by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2 \sigma^2)}$.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was missing. One approximates the other, so I shouldn't expect them to match. And how good the approximation is depends on $\sigma$, which explains why the authors recommend one over the other for my application.

Comment: I'd like to study this further, but I'm not sure where to look. Googling for error function gives me many pages with definitions, but not much introductory explanation. Can you suggest a source (web or book) that provides a student introduction to the application of error functions to modeling? I've been looking through some non-linear regression books, but haven't found any that even list error function in the index.

Comment: @Tyler I mean, the connection between the error function and the integral of the pdf of a Gaussian is just a scale factor ($\sqrt{2}$s float around because of differences in convention). That is the main usage of the error function that I know of.